# How to store many file handles so that we can close it at a later stage

Tags: python, file-handling

I have written a small program in python where I need to open many files and close it at a later stage, I have stored all the file handles in a list so that I can refer to it later for closing.

In my program I am storing all the file handles (*fout*) in the list *foutList[]*

```
for cnt in range(count):
            fileName = "file" + `cnt` + ".txt"
            fullFileName = path + fileName
            print "opening file " + fullFileName
            try:
                    fout = open(fullFileName,"r")
                    foutList.append(fout)
            except IOError as e:
                    print "Cannot open file: %s" % e.strerror
                    break
```

Some people suggested me that do no store it in a List, but did not give me the reason why. Can anyone explain why it is not recommended to store it in a List and what is the other possible way to do the same ?

Comment: you could perhaps create a function that, instead of returning foutList, it returns fout each time using pythons yield. e.g. "yield fout"

Answer (score 3):

I can't think of any reasons why this is really evil, but possible objections to doing this might include:

1. It's hard to guarantee that every single file handle will be closed when you're done. Using the file handle with a context manager (see the `with open(filename) as file_handle:` syntax) always guarantees the file handle is closed, even if something goes wrong.
2. Keeping lots of files open at the same time may be impolite if you're going to have them open for a long time, and another program is trying to access the files.

This said - *why* do you want to keep a whole bunch of files open for writing? If you're writing intermittently to a bunch of files, a better way to do this is to open the file, write to it, and then close it *until you're ready to write again.*

All you have to do is open the file in **append** mode - `open(filename,'a')`. This lets you write to the end of an existing file without erasing what's already there (like the `'w'` mode.)

---

Edit(1) I slightly misread your question - I thought you wanted to open these files for *writing*, not reading. Keeping a bunch of files open for reading isn't too bad.

If you have the files open because you want to *monitor the files for changes*, try using your platform's equivalent of Linux's `inotify`, which will *tell* you when a file has changed (without you having to look at it repeatedly.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Well I am testing a product where I have to open many files simultaneously and keep it open for some time before I close it. Also I have the same program running many times to check the locking process. Will the `with open(filename) as file_handle:` serve in this case ??

Comment: Probably not. If you really do want to open a bunch of files and keep them all open, your approach is fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't store them at all, they will eventually be garbage collected, which will close them.

If you really want to close them manually, use weak references to hold them, which will not prevent garbage collection: http://docs.python.org/library/weakref.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply, But then again in this case, I have to store all the weak reference in a List or some kind of array, right ?? Correct me if I am wrong. Well I am closing all the file handles in my program also in a later stage, I just wanted to know, is storing all the file handles in a List a Bad programming practice ?

Comment: @Gaara There's nothing bad about storing anything in a list. That is what lists are for. The only question is whether the list is the appropriate structure for the situation. You have not provided any information that suggests that the list is inappropriate. My main concern is that maybe you should not be storing the file handles at all.

Comment: Ok, I may be a noob in asking this, but if I dont store the file handles then how will I close the opened files ? In my case I have to keep it open for sometime and then close it.